# Calculating big-o, nested loops

Tags: java, loops, nested, big-o

I have a quick question regarding these nested loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)

        for(j = i; j < N; j = j/2)

}
```

I am seeing here at first loop we go O(N) times, second we go O(N) times and lastly we go O(log n). Is it wrong to say this adds up to O(N)?

Comment: The second and third loops both modify `j`...

Comment: The code as it stands would be O(infinity), because `j` decreases in the inner loop but is only bounded from above.

Comment: O(N) * O(N) * O(logn) = O(n^2logn)

Comment: @nafas Yea thats exactly the answer I want, but this is an old exam question and the answer is O(N) apparently, thats why I am confused.

Comment: @Börje perhaps you meant `j = j * 2` instead of `j = j / 2` for the inner loop? (for the reason I stated above); however that would also give O(infinity) as the initial value of `i` is zero.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Nah, the question is identic to the exam question. It states j = j/2

Comment: Then I'm afraid the answer is O(infinity). Trace through the execution of the code and you'll see why.

Comment: @Börje if u haven't made a mistake, then this loop will never terminate (unless N==0)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yea that is weird. Maybe they made an error when printing this question then because this is exactly what the question looks like and the  question itself is "calculate big-o of following loops. I appreciate the quick response from you guys btw!

Comment: @Börje, the code fragment doesn't have a mathematical solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

> this is an endless loop instead of **j/2** I think it should be
> **j*2**

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the comments, right now this is O(infinity) since the third loop never stops, so ill assume you meant to write this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)

        for(k = i; k < N; k = k*2)

}
```

and in this case, the first and second loop will be O(N) and the third loop will be O(log(N)), but since the loops are nested the total complexity of your code will be

```
O(N*N*log(N)) = O(N^2 * Log(N))
```

if you have any questions about my answer feel free to ask in the comments , and if my comment helped you please consider marking it as the answer or upvoting :)